# Generate multiple word document from foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net-core, syncfusion

I need to generate multiple word document and downloads to disk using a foreach loop. For word document I am using Syncfusion. I am able to download only one document from my program. That because I am using return statement inside the loop. How can I continue loop after return or there is any method to do it without return inside the loop?
Here is my code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateDocument(int? id)
    {
        string text = "some text"
        List<OrderUser> teamList = await _context.OrderUser.Where(o => o.OrderId == id).Include(o => o.Order).Include(o => o.ApplicationUser).ToListAsync();
        using (WordDocument document = new WordDocument())
        {
            IWSection section = document.AddSection();
            IWParagraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();

            paragraph.AppendText(text);

            foreach (var item in teamList)
            {
                paragraph.AppendText("Mr " + item.ApplicationUser.DisplayName);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

                document.Save(stream, FormatType.Docx);

                stream.Position = 0;

                return File(stream, "application/msword", "Result.docx");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it it not possible to send multiple "documents" back via HTTP.

You could try to keep the files in memery or store them in a temporary folder and then zip all files together and return the zip file to the user.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this requirement, you can add the Word document to zip file and save the multiple Word document in single zip file using Syncfusion.Compression. To meet your requirement, we suggest you to use the below code snippet to download multiple Word document in single download.

```
public IActionResult Index(string button)
{
if (button == null)
return View();

string text = "some text";
List<string> items = new List<string>(){ "First","Second","Third","Fourth"};
//Initializes new instance of ZipAchive
ZipArchive zipArchive = new Syncfusion.Compression.Zip.ZipArchive();
//Sets compression level for new items
zipArchive.DefaultCompressionLevel = Syncfusion.Compression.CompressionLevel.Best;
for(int i=0;i<items.Count;i++)
{
using (WordDocument document = new WordDocument())
{
//Adds new section to the document
IWSection section = document.AddSection();
//Add new paragraph to the section
IWParagraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
//Appends the specified text to the paragraph
paragraph.AppendText(text);
paragraph.AppendText(items[i]);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
//Save the document
document.Save(stream, FormatType.Docx);
stream.Position = 0;
//Adds new item to the archive
zipArchive.AddItem("Sample"+i.ToString()+ ".docx", stream, false, (Syncfusion.Compression.FileAttributes)FileAttributes.Normal);
}
}
//Zips the filename
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
//Saves the zip file
zipArchive.Save(memoryStream, false);
return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Attachments.zip");
}
```

Refer for more information:
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/1922/is-it-possible-to-create-the-zip-files-using-syncfusion-compression-zip

Note: Works for Syncfusion.